# PHP JSON Encode with nl2br

Tags: php, mysql, json

the following code I use to populate t able via AJAX -

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_task_comments WHERE web_task_id = '$taskId' 
            ORDER BY log_date DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            $arr[] = $obj;      
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

There is a row in the DB that will need nl2br() and then pass that back to AJAX request. How do I do this with my current setup? Can you use MySQL to convert nl to br in the query?

Thanks
Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE`-function of MySQL to replace all newlines and carriages `\n` and `\r\n` by `<br />`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/replace.html